# TZ Var to Java TimeZone?

Tags: java, timezone

I need to convert from the Unix TZ environment variable of the form:

```
stdoffset[dst[offset][,start[/time],end[/time]]]
```

into a Java TimeZone object.

For example, convert `AEST-10AEDT-11,M10.1.0/02:00:00,M4.1.0/03:00:00` into a Java TimeZone object that represents "Australia\Sydney". Before I go and write the code myself I'd like to know I'm not inventing the wheel again, so does anyone know if there's a library already available that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

It will be really hard to write such a conversion program. On Unix, you can have customized daylight rules and Java provides no such facility. It's possible to search through tzfile trying to find a match but you have to convert the TZ rule into the format used by tzfile, an enormous task.

Why don't you use the same zone id used in Java? For example, you can set TZ as,

export TZ=Australia/Sydney

This is supported on most modern Unix systems (like Linux, Mac OS X). Search `/etc/zoneinfo` or `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. If you can find a file for your timezone, the ID will work.

I also started on a custom TimeZone to handle the old TZ format but I was able to convince the sysadmin to use the zone id so I didn't finish it. The difficult part is to implement the `useDaylightTime()` because the rules used in TZ is very complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I thought as much.

Comment: By the way, in modern Java (8+), the time zone would be represented with [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class: `ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" )`. Note the forward-slash as seen in this Answer but in contrast to the backslash seen in the Question.

Comment: This Answer is correct. FYI, in modern Java, see the `ZoneId` and `ZoneRules` classes. You can get information about offsets and transitions (Daylight Saving Time cut-over, and such). But since many time zones may coincidentally share the same offset, you cannot know for sure which is the zone you want.