# Does the JRE support posix TZ description rather than TZ name?

Tags: java, linux, datetime

Java doesn't appear to apply DST offset when the OS uses a POSIX time zone *description* rather than a time zone *name*.  Is the use of a TZ description unsupported by the JRE or is this behavior a bug?

More details...

I'm working on a Linux (Debian) based system where the TZ environment variable is set to a POSIX formatted TZ like `STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00` instead of a TZ name such as `America/Denver`.  (See [TZ Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html))

While this seems to work correctly for `date` and related system tools, when I try to find the time in a java application, it doesn't appear it has been correctly adjust for DST.  This results in the time being wrong for part of the year when DST is in effect.

I've tested this on a several different systems and seen the same results on each (test w/ results are below)

This behavior actually surfaced in an application that uses [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) but I've since been able to reproduce the issue with the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CheckTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("Current time " + now.toString());
        System.out.println("Current time zone " + tz.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("Current time zone in DST? " + tz.inDaylightTime(now));
    }
}
```

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (bionic)

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

$ export TZ="STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 07:02:27 DST 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 06:02:30 GMT-07:00 2019
Current timezone GMT-07:00
Current timezone in DST? false

$ export TZ="America/Denver"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 07:03:29 MDT 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 07:03:32 MDT 2019
Current timezone Mountain Standard Time
Current timezone in DST? true
```

Custom ARM32hf build, based on debian (kernel 4.1.0-altera)

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu Embedded 8.27.0.91-linux-aarch32hf) (build 1.8.0_162-b91)

$ export TZ="STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 07:06:59 DST 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 06:07:03 GMT-07:00 2019
Current time zone GMT-07:00
Current time zone in DST? false

$ export TZ="America/Denver"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 07:09:45 MDT 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 07:09:49 MDT 2019
Current time zone Mountain Standard Time
Current time zone in DST? true
```

Raspbian 9.9 (stretch)

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

$ export TZ="STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 07:12:52 DST 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 06:12:57 GMT-07:00 2019
Current time zone GMT-07:00
Current time zone in DST? false

$ export TZ="America/Denver"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 07:13:42 MDT 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 07:13:44 MDT 2019
Current time zone Mountain Standard Time
Current time zone in DST? true
```

**EDIT**

Curiously, I see slightly different results on a mac.  Java still doesn't report that the system is in DST, but it at least reports the correct local time.

MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave)

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)

$ export TZ="STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 09:47:14 DST 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 09:47:18 GMT-06:00 2019
Current timezone GMT-06:00
Current timezone in DST? false

$ export TZ="America/Denver"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 09:49:04 MDT 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 09:49:08 MDT 2019
Current timezone Mountain Standard Time
Current timezone in DST? true

$java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

$ export TZ="STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 10:19:23 DST 2019
$java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 10:19:40 GMT-06:00 2019
Current timezone GMT-06:00
Current timezone in DST? false

$ export TZ="America/Denver"
$ date
Fri Aug  9 10:21:03 MDT 2019
$ java CheckTime
Current time Fri Aug 09 10:21:07 MDT 2019
Current timezone Mountain Standard Time
Current timezone in DST? true
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but it's worth mentioning: The classes `TimeZone` and `Date` are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead I recommend you use `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I would immediately expect the same results, though we can't be sure until we've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug.  It is a feature.

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) for `ZoneId`, that POSIX syntax for specifying zones is not supported:

> ### Time-zone IDs
>
> The ID is unique within the system. There are three types of ID.
>
> The simplest type of ID is that from ZoneOffset. This consists of 'Z'
> and IDs starting with '+' or '-'.
>
> The next type of ID are offset-style IDs with some form of prefix,
> such as 'GMT+2' or 'UTC+01:00'. The recognised prefixes are 'UTC',
> 'GMT' and 'UT'. The offset is the suffix and will be normalized during
> creation. These IDs can be normalized to a ZoneOffset using
> normalized().
>
> The third type of ID are region-based IDs. A region-based ID must be
> of two or more characters, and not start with 'UTC', 'GMT', 'UT' '+'
> or '-'. Region-based IDs are defined by configuration, see
> ZoneRulesProvider. The configuration focuses on providing the lookup
> from the ID to the underlying ZoneRules.
>
> Time-zone rules are defined by governments and change frequently.
> There are a number of organizations, known here as groups, that
> monitor time-zone changes and collate them. The default group is the
> IANA Time Zone Database (TZDB). Other organizations include IATA (the
> airline industry body) and Microsoft.
>
> Each group defines its own format for the region ID it provides. The
> TZDB group defines IDs such as 'Europe/London' or 'America/New_York'.
> TZDB IDs take precedence over other groups.

See also:

- [TZ Var to Java TimeZone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382309/tz-var-to-java-timezone)

If you wrote some code to parse that syntax, you should be able to use the data to construct a `SimpleTimeZone` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html)).   Unfortunately, this forces you to continue using the old ("mostly deprecated") `Date` class and friends.

The new (in Java 8) `java.time.*` classes don't appear to have an easy way to construct your own `ZoneId` from a set of rules.  (Maybe it could be done by implementing your own `ZoneRuleProvider` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html)), but it looks complicated.)

So (IMO) you would be better off getting your OS to use the standard TZDB zone ids.

---

You commented:

> On this particular system, neither "/etc/localtime" nor "/etc/timezone" exist.

If you are running Ubuntu Bionic, "/etc/localtime" should exist.  It should be a symlink to a binary timezone file in the "/usr/share/zoneinfo" tree.  See https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-or-change-timezone-on-ubuntu-18-04/.  Or perhaps the problem is that the system has been deliberately configured to not know its local timezone.

Comment: I'm not trying to convert the TZ description to an IANA TZ name.  It seems the TZ description is at least partially parsed as I'm getting standard time for the locale.  If the format was completely unsupported, I'd expect java would fall back to the hwclock (UTC).

I fully agree, using the IANA zone names would be preferable but I'm working on a system where using the TZ description gives us more flexibility to adjust to TZ changes in the future w/o needing to update the TZ database.

Comment: *"It seems the TZ description is at least partially parsed as I'm getting standard time for the locale."* - That does not follow.  Another explanation is that it is failing completely and picking up the local time zone from another source; e.g. "/etc/timezone" or "/etc/localtime".   The implementation knows about both of those files.

Comment: But as I said, if you want to use the POSIX format, it would be feasible to write your own parser, parse the TZ, construct a `SimpleTimeZone` and call `TimeZone::setDefault`

Comment: On this particular system, neither `/etc/localtime` nor `/etc/timezone` exist.  So I'm pretty confident the JVM isn't falling back to either of those, but I agree there could be some other system fallback that I'm missing.  Also worth noting if I set the TZ to something completely non-standard format (`export TZ="foo"`), I get the hwclock time (UTC) from both `date` and java.  In that case, java reports the TZ as GMT.

Comment: Was hoping I could avoid manually parsing the TZ description, but that's a good idea.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57433197/642706) is correct, and should be accepted. Here are a few other thoughts.

> uses a POSIX time zone description

That is not really a time zone at all. It is focused on mere offset-from-UTC values (a number of hours-minutes-seconds), conjoined with a 2-4 character pseudo-zone such as `IST` or `CST` which are *not* standardized and not unique! For example, `IST` can be India Standard Time, Irish Standard Time, or others. `CST` can be at least Central Standard Time (in the Americas) or China Standard Time.

> "STD+7DST+6,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00"

What an ugly, error-prone way to handle time zones.

As, Stephen C suggests, if you must wrestle such inputs, try to parse them to deduce a real time zone or offset-from-UTC.

If you have a limited domain of expected inputs, perhaps just do a simple hard-coded mapping. For example, a string starting with `STD+7DST+6` maps to `America/Denver`. Notice that the latter part of that input string may vary over time as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is often redefined.

> I'd expect java would fall back to the hwclock (UTC).

A computer hardware clock is not really aware of offsets or zones. Software makes sense of the underlying count kept by the clock.

The host OS watching the hardware clock has its own default time zone used when reporting the current moment.

A running Java app never looks at the host OS’ current default time zone. The JVM maintains its own current default time zone. This value *may* default to that of the host OS upon launch of the JVM. But the JVM’s current [default time zone can be altered](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) at any moment by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM. That is why your code should never rely upon the JVM’s current default time zone when the zone is crucial; always specify the desired/expected zone by passing a `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` as optional argument in various methods.

To see the JVM’s current default time zone, call `ZoneId.systemDefault`. But as I said, better to not rely on the default.

> I fully agree, using the IANA zone names would be preferable

Yes, absolutely, you should be using [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the `Continent/Region` format.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

> I'm working on a system where using the TZ description gives us more flexibility to adjust to TZ changes in the future w/o needing to update the TZ database.

You can do what you'd like, of course. But this seems like poor judgement to me. Trying to keep up with time zone formal definitions and changes is quite a chore.

This work is already being done for you in the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tz_database) project. This data is included within your Java implementation. Java updates come with *tzdata* updates. If there is an urgent change not yet available through a Java update, you can replace the *tzdata* yourself within Java. This is certainly much simpler than writing code to massage ambiguous unstandardized pseudo-zones.

> (See TZ Variable)

[POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) and OS level tools such as [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)/glibc are not up to the task of date-time handling and localization and such. The subtleties, complexities, and never-ending changes are beyond the capacity of the Unix-level OS libraries. For date-time handling, use *tzdata* and the *java.time* classes. Similarly, for localization, use [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) and [CLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) from the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium) rather than POSIX-level calls. Java bundles these modern alternatives to libc, and later versions of Java use them by default.

> TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
>
> Date now = new Date();

These date-time classes are simply terrible, bloody-awful, and should be avoided. They were designed and implemented by people who did not understand date-time handling.

These legacy classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Specifically, `Date` is replaced by `Instant` (both represent a moment in UTC), and `TimeZone` by `ZoneId`.

Legacy code:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
Date now = new Date();
System.out.println("Current time " + now.toString());
System.out.println("Current time zone " + tz.getDisplayName());
System.out.println("Current time zone in DST? " + tz.inDaylightTime(now));
```

Modern code:

```
Instant now = Instant.now ();
System.out.println ( "Current time in UTC: " + now.toString () );

ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault ();
System.out.println ( "Current time zone " + z.toString () );
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atZone ( z ); // Adjust from UTC to a time zone.
System.out.println ( "Current time in default zone: " + zdt );
System.out.println ( "Current moment in current default time zone is in Daylight Saving Time:  " + z.getRules ().isDaylightSavings ( now ) );
```

When run.

> Current time in UTC: 2019-08-09T19:36:33.134669Z
>
> Current time zone America/Los_Angeles
>
> Current time in default zone: 2019-08-09T12:36:33.134669-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> Current moment in current default time zone is in Daylight Saving Time:  true